# What if the nameservers stored at the registrar for a domain answer non-authorative?

Tags: dns

In what way are resolvers concerned or affected by having a non-authorative response from the primary and all available secondary nameservers?

Would a setup like this where the primary master nameserver is listed in the public NS records result in problems? If so, what kind of problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terms *primary* and *secondary nameservers* is usually used to denote the authoritative ("official") name servers of a certain domain. For example, `NS-1029.AWSDNS-00.ORG` is one of the authoritative name servers for the domain `stackexchange.com`, i.e. it gives authoritative responses (by definition) for this domain.

A name server can also be a (caching) recursive name server, which you can ask to do a lookup for any domain. A name server like this is hardly ever the authoritative name server for any random domain you query, so they respond with a non-authoritative answer.

Your local resolver libraries do not know that these are somehow "blessed" name servers, they are only aware of the name servers you have configured in, for example, `/etc/resolv.conf`.

A response to a query being non-authoritative hardly matters to a resolver, it is the best response available using the configured mechanism.

Comment: Cool cool *"A response to a query being non-authoritative hardly matters to a resolver, it is the best response available using the configured mechanism."* is exactly what I was looking for.